# Can you get a menu item's width before displaying the menu item in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, width, menuitem

I'm trying to get the menu width of a menu item in flex 4. I can get it but I have to show the menu first, then hide the menu, do a calculation, and show it again. Is there an easier way to get the item menu width without this hassle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `validateNow()`?

For more info, check out:

http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2008/09/07/what-is-validatenow-and-why-you-should-know/ 
http://www.developmentarc.com/site/sites/default/files/understanding_the_flex_3_lifecycle_v1.0.pdf (PDF)

**Edit:**
Take a look at `TextLineMetrics`: http://blog.grio.com/2009/10/wrangling-flex-labels-autosizing-text.html

Comment: Yep, doesn't seem to be working. :\ Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Dennis, I added another link about `TextLineMetrics` that someone else posted about on another question I was helping on. Maybe it will help you too. :)